# What is the chemical test for identification of benzophenone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

> How to identify that a unknown compound is benzophenone?

**My working:-**

First I added 2,4- DNP(2,4-Dinitrophenyl hydrazine) to the compound. Yellow-orange crystals were formed which indicated presence of carbonyl group. Then, I added Tollen's reagent to the compound. It did not gave silver mirror which means aldehyde group is absent. So, it must be a ketone. So, I added m-Dinitrobenzene to the compound. It did not gave violet colour. Alternatively, I added Sodium nitroprusside to the compound. It did not gave a red color. Both the test is for confirmation of ketone compound.

I asked my teacher what is the unknown compound. He said that it is benzophenone. Also, in the practical book where all the chemical test were mentioned, it was mentioned  as a side-note that benzophenone does not give the above mentioned test. So, what is the chemical test for identification of benzophenone?

Comment: You can use iodoform test after Tollens test.

Comment: @AdityaDev, benzophenone will not give iodoform test because it does not contain ketomethyl group       ($\ce{-CH3CO}$).

Comment: oops. i thought benzophenone was CH3-CO-ph. my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After identification of ketone, to identify benzophenone you need to find the range of melting point using melting point apparatus which you should get in range of $48.3\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ to $50.6\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$.

Then you can find IR of unknown(benzophenone).

Source: [Prezi](https://prezi.com/c3kelwvofz5a/identification-of-unknowns/)

Answer (score 0):

experiment
To 50 mg of benzophenone taken in a dry test tube add 1 gm of naphthalene mix and heat until melts. Add a small piece of sodium metal and heat again.
observation
The mixture turns green due to the free radical formation which is in delocalisation  with two phenyl rings

Comment: Could you provide a source from which you found the experiment?

Comment: @koteswararao D  How do you say that the radical will be formed in the benzophenone? A radical anion formation in naphthalene with sodium is known.